# How to add items into an array that are in the struct but not in the Db table using GRDB

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, grdb

In the My_Quotes table (see MyQuotes struct below) in the Db I am storing the ID of the contact that was selected from the users Contacts on the device. This way if the contacts information is changed the ID remains constant. So I pull the ContactID from the My_Quotes table in the Db and use it to build the ContactFullName, ContactFirst, ContactLast and ContactOrg with func get_ContactName_Org.

The problem I'm having is that ContactFullName, ContactFirst, ContactLast and ContactOrg (see QuoteList struct below) are not in the My_Quotes table. The error is: Fatal error: could not read String from missing column ContactFullName

I understand the error but adding these items into the My_Quotes table causes a host of other problems.
How can I insert these items into theArray?

```
        var theArray = [QuoteList]()

        do {
            try dbQueue_GRDB.read { db in
                for quotes in try QuoteList.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM My_Quotes ORDER BY QuoteID")
                {
                    let fullString = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).fullStaring
                    let first = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).firstName
                    let last = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).lastName
                    let org = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).clientOrg

                    theArray.append(QuoteList(QuoteID: quotes.QuoteID,
                                              Quote_Number: quotes.Quote_Number,
                                              Quote_Status: quotes.Quote_Status,
                                              ContactID: quotes.ContactID,
                                              ContactFullName: fullString, // This is not in the My_Quotes table
                                              ContactFirst: first, // This is not in the My_Quotes table
                                              ContactLast: last, // This is not in the My_Quotes table
                                              ContactOrg: org, // This is not in the My_Quotes table
                                              Inv_ID: quotes.Inv_ID,
                                              Locked_Bool: quotes.Locked_Bool))
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't populate the quote list! \(error)")
        }


    static func get_ContactName_Org(contactID: String) -> (firstName: String, lastName: String, clientOrg: String, fullStaring: String)
    {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        var theName = CNContact()
        var theStaring: String = ""
        var firstName: String = ""
        var lastName: String = ""
        var clientOrg: String = ""
        
        do {
            theName = try store.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contactID, keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
            
        } catch {
            print("Fetching contact data failed: \(error)")
        }
        
        firstName = theName.givenName
        lastName = theName.familyName
        clientOrg = theName.organizationName
        
        theStaring = theName.organizationName == "" ? theName.givenName + " " + theName.familyName : theName.givenName + " " + theName.familyName + ", " + theName.organizationName
        
        return (firstName,lastName,clientOrg,theStaring)
    }
    

struct QuoteList: Codable, FetchableRecord
{
    let QuoteID: Int64
    var Quote_Number: String
    var Quote_Status: String
    var ContactID: String
    var ContactFullName: String // This is not in the My_Quotes table
    var ContactFirst: String // This is not in the My_Quotes table
    var ContactLast: String // This is not in the My_Quotes table
    var ContactOrg: String // This is not in the My_Quotes table
    var Inv_ID: Int64?
    var Locked_Bool: String
}


struct MyQuotes: Codable, FetchableRecord
{
    let QuoteID: Int64
    var Quote_Number: String
    var Quote_Date: String
    var Quote_Status: String
    var NumOf_People: String?
    var Event_Venue: String?
    var Routine_ID: Int64?
    var Routine_Price: Double?
    var Quote_Deposit: Double?
    var Deposit_Date: String?
    var Age_Range: String?
    var Lodging_Exp: Double?
    var Gas_Exp: Double?
    var Meals_Exp: Double?
    var Miscel_Exp: Double?
    var Airfare_Exp: Double?
    var Show_Start: String?
    var Show_End: String?
    var Show_Date: String?
    var Notes_Exp: String?
    var ContactID: String
    var Quote_Rejection: String?
    var Inv_ID: Int64?
    var Quote_Discount: Int?
    var Locked_Bool: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not have `QuoteList` adopt the `FetchableRecord`. Why? Because the database rows do not contain enough information to build `QuoteList`. `FetchableRecord` comes with an `init(row: Row)` initializer that is impossible to correctly fulfill, as the fatal error tells you. It is a programmer error to have `QuoteList` adopt `FetchableRecord` and feed it with database rows that do not contain enough information.

`FetchableRecord` is a protocol that comes with handy fetching methods, and that's why you were attracted by it. But now that it is clear that `QuoteList` needs something else, it is time to fetch *differently*.

One possible technique is to fetch raw database rows:

```
// Instead of:
// for quotes in try QuoteList.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM My_Quotes ORDER BY QuoteID")
for rows in try Row.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM My_Quotes ORDER BY QuoteID") {
    let fullString = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).fullStaring
    let first = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).firstName
    let last = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).lastName
    let org = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).clientOrg
    
    let quoteList = QuoteList(
        QuoteID: row["QuoteID"],
        Quote_Number: row["Quote_Number"],
        Quote_Status: row["Quote_Status"],
        ContactID: row["ContactID"],
        ContactFullName: fullString,
        ContactFirst: first,
        ContactLast: last,
        ContactOrg: org,
        Inv_ID: row["Inv_ID"],
        Locked_Bool: row["Locked_Bool"])
    
    theArray.append(quoteList)
}
```

Another technique is to define an actually fetchable model:

```
struct PartialQuoteList: Codable, FetchableRecord
{
    let QuoteID: Int64
    var Quote_Number: String
    var Quote_Status: String
    var ContactID: String
    var Inv_ID: Int64?
    var Locked_Bool: String
}
for partial in try PartialQuoteList.fetchAll(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM My_Quotes ORDER BY QuoteID") {
    let fullString = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).fullStaring
    let first = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).firstName
    let last = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).lastName
    let org = ModelData.get_ContactName_Org(contactID: quotes.ContactID).clientOrg
    
    let quoteList = QuoteList(
        QuoteID: partial.QuoteID,
        Quote_Number: partial.Quote_Number,
        Quote_Status: partial.Quote_Status,
        ContactID: partial.ContactID,
        ContactFullName: fullString,
        ContactFirst: first,
        ContactLast: last,
        ContactOrg: org,
        Inv_ID: partial.Inv_ID
        Locked_Bool: partial.Locked_Bool)
    
    theArray.append(quoteList)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gwendal. This worked and it's just what I needed. This also answered what would have been my next question.